# Spring: Authorization header is always null via Angular app

Tags: angular, spring, jwt

I'm building an application with **Spring** and **Angular** and for now, I'm trying to implement the security phase using **Spring security and (JWT)**
The problem is that when I send the **Authorization header** from **Angular** Spring does not receive it!
even tho I'm sure it's already in the request (from chrome dev tools).
Also when I send the same request with the same header from **ARC (Advanced REST Client from chrome)** spring receives it and returns the data!
On then Angular side I'm using the `HttpInterceptor` of course to add the token to requests like so:

```
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{
  private _api = `${environment.api}/api`;
  constructor(
    private _authService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

    if(req.url.startsWith(this._api)){
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this._authService.getToken()}`
        }
      });
    }
    
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

[image]

And this is what I'm doing inside spring:

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    private List<String> excludedURLsPattern = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"/authenticate"});

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {

        return excludedURLsPattern
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(urlPattern -> request.getRequestURL().toString().contains(urlPattern));

    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("=== request URL: "+request.getRequestURL());
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        System.out.println("=== requestTokenHeader: "+requestTokenHeader);// in this line I always get null (when using Angular not ARC) !!

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        // Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
            // authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

And this is the message I get:

```
2020-10-14 15:11:17.664  WARN 9856 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.s.c.security.config.JwtRequestFilter   : JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok I will leave the solution here in case someone needed it.
as described in [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) and since I'm using **Sring Security** I must enable **CORS at Spring security level**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()...// this one right here
    }
}
```

Comment: This way of enabling `cors` is depreciated and marked for removal. For newer versions, easiest way to enable cors is; `htttp.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())`

Answer (score 0):

**Springboot-3**

under your security configuration class `public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)` bean
add following line before `http.build()` anywhere
`cors(Customizer.withDefaults())` and create a new class as global configuration `CorsConfiguration` implement method `addCorsMapping` from `WebMvcConfigurer` class, finally allow methods, originas, header under implemented method, this should work